# Why couldn't Deanna Troi detect the presence of ensign Ro and LaForge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, betazoid

In The Next Phase, they were invisible. Why couldn't Counselor Troi sense them?

Comment: Maybe her telepathic / empathic abilities only work on people in phase instead of out of phase?

Comment: Or maybe she's secretly jealous of them and is playing dumb.

Comment: "they were invisible" — There were out of phase. Invisibility was only a side effect of that.

Comment: the guys on MissionLog jokingly speculate it's because she can feel the grief of the entire crew over their loss and it has debilitated her - she has a massive headache and is passed out :D - http://www.missionlogpodcast.com/the-next-phase

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious. If Ro and Geordi can't interact with matter, so that they are essentially no longer part of the normal space-time continuum, how in the world could Troi sense them?

Answer (score 9):

### We do not know, as Troi hasn't spoken anything during the episode

Well, as the heading says, according to [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/224.htm), the only scripted response from Counsellor Troi is shaking her head, acknowledging that she cannot sense their presence.

> PICARD: Mister Data, begin a level one diagnostic. All transporter
>   systems offline until further notice. Could they have materialised
>   somewhere else?
>   DATA: Negative, Captain. Sensors are unable to locate
>   them anywhere within transporter range.  PICARD: Counsellor?
>   **(Troi shakes her head)**

Additionally, from the screenplay (thanks to Valorum for the resource):

> PICARD
>
> (to Troi)
>
> Counselor?
>
> *Troi waits a beat and silently "listens"... but her  expression is
>   grim. She shakes her head. That seems     to seal the fate of their
>   friends. But there is no  time to mourn.*

She has never mentioned that her abilities will not work with beings that are out of phase.

Nevertheless, being out of phase and being unreachable for both ship's sensors and telepathic/empathic abilities, may suggest the reason. It is still a guess, though.

Comment: You might want to add in a quote from the screenplay; http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/224.txt regarding Troi "*listening*" for them but hearing nothing

Comment: @Valorum - thank you! I will add this and keep the resource for future answers :)